# Locally obtain three.js scene from canvas element for manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, scope, three.js

Do Three.js variables (scene, camera, renderer etc.) *need* to be kept globally?

I have created a function which initialises canvas elements, taking a DOM position and other information to construct the scene. This function then passes to a render function, which calls itself meaning I never lose the variables.

The issue I'm facing is when I want to manipulate the scene, I don't have access to those variables unless I turn them global. Is there any way currently available to access and manipulate the scene using just the canvas element ID? I was looking at the canvas.getContext() function but I can't see a way to get what I want.

I have always avoided global variables since I understood it was generally bad practice, but is it the best solution in this case regardless?

Here is some code to help clarify what I mean.

```
function initCanvas(domPos, items){
    var scene, camera, renderer, loader;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    /* canvas, camera, controls setup ... */

    domPos.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
        loader.load(items[i], function (obj){ scene.add(obj); });
    }
    render(renderer, scene, controls, camera);
}

function render(r, s, ctrl, cam){
    requestAnimationFrame(function(){ render(r, s, ctrl, cam); });
    r.render(s, cam);
    ctrl.update();
}

function manipCanvas(canvasID, item){
    // var scene = document.getElementByID(canvasID).scene;
    // var scene = document.getElementByID(canvasID).getContext().scene;
    loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
    loader.load(item, function (obj){ scene.add(obj); });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try assign it to the canvas:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
document.getElementById(canvasID).scene=scene;
```

But i think it's ok to use global variable in a simple page.